# How to calculate Standardized Mean Difference after matching?

Tags: standard-deviation, matching

The above question seems quite trivial. Calculating it by hand leads to sensible answer, yet this answer is not in line with the calculated smd by the MatchBalance function in R.

See below two different ways to calculate smd after matching. While calculating by hand produces a smd of 0.009(which is the same as produced by the smd and TableOne functions in R), the MatchBalance comes up with a standardized mean differences of 11.317(more than 1000 times as large.

My question therefore is:

- Is the "std mean diff" listed in MatchBalance something different than the smd? (and if yes, how can it be interpreted?)
- What am I missing?
- Or do I need to consider this an error in MatchBalance? (which seems unexpected to me as it has already been around for quite some time)

  ```
  #install.packages("Matching")
  library(Matching)
  data(lalonde)

  #Estimate the propensity model
  glm1  <- glm(treat~age + I(age^2) + educ + I(educ^2) + black +
           hisp + married + nodegr + re74  + I(re74^2) + re75 + I(re75^2) +
           u74 + u75, family=binomial, data=lalonde)

  #save data objects
  X  <- glm1$fitted
  Y  <- lalonde$re78
  Tr  <- lalonde$treat

  # Run matching and summarise output
  rr  <- Match(Y=Y,Tr=Tr,X=X,M=1)
  summary(rr)


  # Let's check the covariate balance in three different ways 

  #1 Matchbalance provides a smd of 0.11.317 for the covariate "age"
  mb  <- MatchBalance(treat~age + I(age^2) + educ + I(educ^2) + black +
                      hisp + married + nodegr + re74  + I(re74^2) + re75 + I(re75^2) +
                      u74 + u75, data=lalonde, match.out=rr, nboots=10)

  #2 Calculation by hand provides a smd of 0.009 for the covariate "age"
  matched_data = lalonde[unlist(rr[c("index.treated","index.control")]),]
  (mean(matched_data$age[matched_data$treat==1])-mean(matched_data$age[matched_data$treat==0]))/sd(matched_data$age)
  ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On why you and `MatchBalance` get different values for the SMD:

First, `MatchBalance` multiplies the SMD by 100, so the actual SMD on the scale of the variable is .11317. That's still much larger than what you get from `TableOne` and your own calculation. That's because of how you created `match_data` and computed the SMD with it.

You will notice that `match_data` has *more* rows than `lalonde`, even though in matching you discarded units. That's because the structure of `index.treated` and `index.control` is not what you expect when you match with ties. Each time a unit is paired, that pair gets its own entry in those formulas. With ties, one treated unit can be matched to many control units (as many as have the same propensity score as each other). Each control unit that that treated unit is matched with adds an entry to `index.treated` for that treated unit. So treated unit that is matched with 4 tied control units will have 4 entries in `index.treated`. That would give them 4 times the weight of another treated unit on your calculation, which is clearly inappropriate because each treated unit should only be counted once, and the contribution of each control unit should correspond to how many ties it has. To address this, `Match` returns a vector of weights in the `weights` component, one for each pair, that represents how much that pair should contribute.

The way `MatchBalance` computes the SMD is by computing the weighted difference in means and dividing by the weighted standard deviation in the treated group. When applying this formula below, we see that we do indeed get the correct answer:

```r
matched_data = lalonde[unlist(rr[c("index.treated","index.control")]),]
w1 <- c(rr$weights, rr$weights)

#Define weighted mean and weighted SD functions
w.m <- function(x, w) sum(x*w)/sum(w)
w.sd <- function(x, w) sqrt(sum(((x - w.m(x,w))^2)*w)/(sum(w)-1))

with(matched_data, (w.m(age[treat==1], w1[treat==1]) - w.m(age[treat==0], w1[treat==0]))/w.sd(age[treat==1], w1[treat==1]))
#> [1] 0.1131677
```

If instead of dealing with this funky strangely-sized dataset, you want to deal with your original dataset with matching weights, where unmatched units are weighted 0 and matched units are weighted based on how many matches they are a part of, you can use the `get.w` function in `cobalt` to extract matching weights from the `Match` object. These are not the same weights provided by the `Match` object; the weights returned by `get.w` have one entry for each unit in the original dataset. We can use the same formula as above with these new weights and you will see the answer is the same:

```r
w2 <- cobalt::get.w(rr, treat = lalonde$treat)
with(lalonde, (w.m(age[treat==1], w2[treat==1]) - w.m(age[treat==0], w2[treat==0]))/w.sd(age[treat==1], w2[treat==1]))
#> [1] 0.1131677
```

Note that `MatchBalance` uses the weighted standard deviation of the treated group as the SF; I believe this is inappropriate, so when you run `bal.tab` in `cobalt` on the `Match` output you will not get the same results; the unweighted standard deviation of the treated group is used instead.

Finally, if you turn off ties by setting `ties = FALSE` in the call to `Match`, then your formula does work if you modify the standard deviation to be that of the matched treated group because all the weights in the `Match` object are equal to 1.

---

Check out my R package `cobalt`, which was specifically designed for assessing balance after propensity score matching because different packages used different formulas for computing the standardized mean difference (SMD). `cobalt` provides several options for computing the SMD; it is not a trivial problem. `Matching`, `MatchIt`, `twang`, `CBPS`, and other packages all use different standards, so I wanted to unify them. You can read more about the motivations for `cobalt` on its [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cobalt/vignettes/cobalt_A0_basic_use.html).

The only thing that differs among methods of computing the SMD is the denominator, the standardization factor (SF). There are a few desiderata for a SF that have been implied in the literature:

- It should be the same before and after matching to ensure difference before and after matching are not due to changes in the SF but rather to changes in the mean difference
- It should reflect the target population of interest

Rubin's early works recommend computing the SF as $\sqrt{\frac{s_1^2 + s_2^2}{2}}$. The What Works Clearinghouse recommends using the small-sample corrected Hedge's $g$, which has its own funky formula (see page 15 of the WWC Procedures Handbook [here](https://ies.ed.gov/ncee/wwc/Handbooks)). You computed the SF simply as the standard deviation of the variable in the combined matched sample. There are many other formulas, which can be controlled in `cobalt` by using the `s.d.denom` argument, described in the documentation for the function `col_w_smd`, which computes (weighted) SMDs.

The standards I use in `cobalt` are the following:

- The SF is always computed in the unadjusted (i.e., pre-matched or unweighted) sample (except in a few cases)
- When the estimand is the ATT or ATC, the SF is the standard deviation of the variable in the focal group (i.e., the treated or control group, respectively)
- When the estimand is the ATE, the SF is computed using Rubin's formula above

The user has the option of setting `s.d.denom` to a few other values, which include `"hedges"` for the small-sample corrected Hedge's $g$, `"all"` for the standard deviation of the variable in the combine unadjusted sample, or `"weighted"` for the standard deviation in the combined adjusted sample, which is what you computed.

There are a few unusual cases. Typically when matching one wants the ATT, but if you discard treated units through common support or a caliper, the target population becomes ambiguous. These cases, `cobalt` treats the estimand as if it were the ATE. When using propensity score weights to estimate the ATO or ATM, the target population is actually defined by the weights, so the SF will be the *weighted* standard deviation, and the same SF will be used before and after weighting to ensure it is constant. There may be a few other weirdnesses here and there that are described in the documentation.

What should you do? It doesn't matter. The SMD is just a heuristic and its exact value isn't as important as how generally close to zero it is. The different ways of computing the SF will not affect its value in most cases. My advice is to use `cobalt`'s defaults or to choose the one you like and enter it when using `cobalt`'s functions. Make sure you are consistent when reporting the results, and it would be best if you include the formula you use in your report.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation. I agree that the exact smd value doesn't matter too much, but rather that it should be as close to zero as possible. While the explanation provides some hints why smd's might vary to some extent, I still do not understand why the smd provided by matchbalance is 1000 times as large.

Comment: I edited my answer to fully explain this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for doing all this effort. It is now clear to me and have upvoted and accepted your answer. Find it still a bit odd that MatchBalance chooses to report these values on a scale 100 times as large

Comment: It's actually not that uncommon to see them reported this way, as "percentage of standard deviations". But it's true, it's not the most common practice and doesn't really serve any utility. Glad this was helpful.

Comment: Can you please accept this answer so that it is not lingering as unanswered?

Comment: I am not sure what happened but I already accepted the answer a few days ago, but now it seem to have vanished. Anyway, I have accepted it again. Thanks again for the help :)

Comment: @Noah This is a great answer. Can you point me to literature that explains how to get weights from matched sets? I failed to find a formula for computing weights for matching with replacement. Thanks!

Comment: @blooraven It is described in a few places. [Hill & Reiter (2006, p 2232)](https://doi.org/10.1002/sim.2277) makes it most clear, but [Abadie & Imbens (2006)](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1468-0262.2006.00655.x) and [Lin et al. (2021)](http://arxiv.org/abs/2112.13506) also discuss this if you read between the lines, the latter showing that matching weights approximate IPW weights. The formula is also described without citation in the `MatchIt` [documentation](https://kosukeimai.github.io/MatchIt/reference/matchit.html#how-matching-weights-are-computed).